# Sodium acetate stoichiometry from baking soda and vinegar

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, synthesis, stoichiometry, home-experiment

I want to make sodium acetate from sodium bicarbonate and vinegar. I'm a bit stumped at calculating amounts of each reagent. I'm starting with 8% acetic acid vinegar. I was going to add, to 1 L of the 8% acid (80 mL acetic acid), 80 grams of bicarb soda. I came to this as the 80 mL acetic acid has a mass of ~83 grams, and I'm guessing I should use an excess of acetic acid. Is this right?

Comment: You should use excess of acid, but excess in terms of the **number of moles**. Reactions occur not by weight, but by moles. Weight of compound = number of moles x molar mass

Answer (score 2):

The density of acetic acid is 1.053 g/ml, so you'll have 80 x 1.053g = 84.24g of acetic acid in 1L. The molecular weight of acetic acid is 60.052 so you have 80 x 1.053/60 = 1.404 moles.  Multiply this by the molecular weight of sodium bicarbonate which is 84.007 to get the weight of sodium bicarbonate required for equivalence = 117.946g.